# Carrier wave does not delete file from memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have two models `User` and `Attachment` where `User has many Attachments` and `Attachment belongs to User`

I am trying to implement a file upload/download service using Carrierwave.

This is how I save the upload :

```
def create
    uploader = LauncherUploader.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment => {:file => [ :original_filename ]}])
    @attachment.name = params[:attachment][:file].original_filename
    @attachment.format = params[:attachment][:file].content_type
    @attachment.user_id = @user.id
    @attachment.save
    uploader.store!(params[:attachment][:file])
    redirect_to user_attachments_path, notice: "The file #{@attachment.name} was uploaded"
  end
```

And this is how I am trying to delete the file:

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) or not_found
    @attachment = @user.attachments.find(params[:id])
    @attachment.destroy
    uploader = LauncherUploader.new
    uploader.remove_attachment!(@attachment)
    redirect_to user_attachments_path, notice:  "The file #{@attachment.name} has been deleted."
  end
```

My Uploader is called `Launcher`. The current `destroy` method deletes the record from the database but not from the memory. What needs to be done to correct this behaviour?

**EDIT**

This is how the current attachments are being displayed

[VIEW]

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= attachment.name %></td>
    <td><%= attachment.format %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Download Link', :action => 'download' , :id => attachment.id  %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'Delete', user_attachment_path(params[:user_id], attachment),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'btn' %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

[CONTROLLER]

```
def index
    @attachments = Attachment.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end
```

Any deleted file does not appear in this list. But continues to exist in the folder where it was uploaded.

Comment: Why do you mean by memory? do you mean that you can see it in the browser when page loads?

Comment: Can you put the code that you show the image?

Comment: @MrH No. I mean that it does not list the file on page load. But the file exists in the folder where it was uploaded.

No database entry, but file still exists in the upload folder.

Comment: Please run the app again then check the log and put it here. Thanks

Comment: There is no Permission issue on the Uploads folder is it?